# Como funciona a função map?

Tags: javascript

Estou estudando *JavaScript*, aprendendo as funções `map()`, `filter()` e `reduce()`, e encontrei um [artigo no medium](https://medium.com/tableless/entendendo-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-funcional-em-javascript-de-uma-vez-c676489be08b), o problema é que eu não consigo entender o porque dessa parte do código retornar `undefined`. Já tentei até colocar o código completo no [pythontutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=const%20students%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20name%3A%20'Anna',%20grade%3A%206%20%7D,%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20name%3A%20'John',%20grade%3A%204%20%7D,%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20name%3A%20'Maria',%20grade%3A%209%20%7D%0A%5D%3B%0A%0Avar%20byName%20%3D%20function%28object%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20object.name%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Avar%20byNames%20%3D%20function%28list%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20list.map%28byName%29%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0AbyNames%28students%29%3B&cumulative=false&curInstr=11&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=js&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false) e mesmo assim nada de conseguir entender.

```
const students = [
    { name: 'Anna', grade: 6 },
    { name: 'John', grade: 4 },
    { name: 'Maria', grade: 9 }
];

var byName = function(object) {
    return object.name
};
console.log(byName(students));
```

Eu esperava isso :

```
// Aqui retornaria a quantidade de name's dentro de students.
var byName = function(object) {
  return object.name; 
};

// Aqui retornaria o valor dentro de cada name ("Anna", "John" e "Maria")
var byNames = function(list) {
  return list.map(byName);
};
```

Comment: O que esperavas que `console.log(byName(students));` retornasse? (só para perceber como estás a pensar)

Comment: Quando dizes _"// Aqui retornaria a quantidade de name's dentro de students."_ queres dizer que esperas como resposta o numero `3` ou uma array com os 3 nomes?

Comment: Desculpa @Sergio♦, eu não reparei que você tinha respondido. Foi mal !!
Eu esperava um array com a quantidade de objetos dentro de students.
Para que eu conseguisse fazer algo tipo: students[0].name e me retornasse "Anna"

Comment: Ainda não tenho a certeza que tens a resposta que procuravas... mas de qq maneira então se queres fazer `students[0].name` e obter `Anna` não precisas de funções... podes fazer diretamente no objeto. Ou percebi mal?

Comment: Na verdade eu fiz a pergunta de uma forma burra kkk.
Eu queria entender como byName(students); retorna undefined e byNames(students); retornar os 3 nomes dentro do objeto, quando o retorno de byNames é list.map(byName); e byName(students) tem retorno undefined.

Comment: `byName(students);` retorna undefined pois essa função procura pela propriedade na array que lhe passaste. é o mesmo que `students.objeto;` que dá undefined. Se usares `byNames(students);` aí vai funcionar como queres com os principios de programação funcional.

Comment: Estou começando a entender. Vou estudar mais!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Map

A função [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) mapeia os elementos de um array para um novo array com o resultado de uma função aplicado a cada elemento.

Pegando no exemplo da documentação, podemos considerar um array de números e utilizar o `map` para obter o dobro de cada um deles da seguinte forma:

```js
var numeros = [1, 5, 10, 15];
var dobros = numeros.map(function(x) {
   return x * 2;
}); 

console.log(dobros); //2, 10, 20, 30
```

Vemos que é chamada a função para cada elemento do array `numeros`, construindo assim um novo elemento para o array `dobros`. Esse elemento é sempre o parâmetro da função utilizada, que no exemplo acima se chama de `x`, embora possa ter qualquer outro nome.

### Problema no seu código

O problema é que a função `byName` espera receber um objeto que tenha a propriedade `name` e que no seu exemplo não tem, pois você passou `students` que é o array inteiro:

```
console.log(byName(students));
```

Para passar um aluno especifico podia fazer assim:

```
console.log(byName(students[0]));
```

Que estaria a obter o nome do primeiro estudante.

Exemplo:

```js
const students = [
    { name: 'Anna', grade: 6 },
    { name: 'John', grade: 4 },
    { name: 'Maria', grade: 9 }
];

var byName = function(object) {
    return object.name
};
console.log(byName(students[0]));
```

No entanto o objetivo desse exercício nem era esse, assim como está mencionado no artigo que referiu, mas sim mapear a lista de alunos para uma lista de nomes através da função `map` e `byName` com:

```
students.map(byName);
```

Que mapeia do array original de alunos, que é um array de objetos, para um novo apenas com os nomes, utilizando a função `byName` devolve somente o nome da cada elemento.

Exemplo:

```js
const students = [
    { name: 'Anna', grade: 6 },
    { name: 'John', grade: 4 },
    { name: 'Maria', grade: 9 }
];

var byName = function(object) {
    return object.name
};

console.log(students.map(byName));
```

Poderia até criar uma segunda função para este mapeamento da lista toda:

```
var byNames = function(list) {
    return list.map(byName);
};
```

E depois utiliza-la apropriadamente:

```
byNames(students); // ["Anna", "John", "Maria"]
```

### Map com Arrow functions

Outra forma ainda mais simplificada utilizando [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) de ES6 seria:

```
students.map(x => x.name);
```

O que faria com que não fosse necessário sequer ter a função `byName`

Aplicando *arrow functions* ao exemplo inicial dos dobros ficaria assim:

```js
var numeros = [1, 5, 10, 15];
var dobros = numeros.map(x => x * 2); 
console.log(dobros); //2, 10, 20, 30
```

Exemplo a funcionar com os `students`:

```js
const students = [
    { name: 'Anna', grade: 6 },
    { name: 'John', grade: 4 },
    { name: 'Maria', grade: 9 }
];

//byName agora com arrow function
console.log(students.map(x => x.name));
```

Comment: Eu tenho mania de ficar rodando o codigo por parte e tentar entender oque acontece, eu já tinha entendido como o map() funcionava, só n entendi o que tava acontecendo nessa parte do codigo. 
Muito boa a sua resposta, obrigado de verdade!